# Sideloading Large App through Device Portal or Visual Studio to Xbox One keeps failing... Why?

Tags: visual-studio, uwp, xbox-one

I have an app which is ~20GB all in all. I'm trying to sideload this to the Xbox One, which I have previously achieved with smaller apps via Visual Studio or the Device Portal.

However, with the big app, I get this error:

```
Error       OperationFailedException: Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component
```

about six times, in the output.

On device portal it just stops after about 20% progress, giving no reason as to why.

Does anyone have any ideas as to why this is happening? I assume it is the size, but then, how would companies test their games?

Any help would be great.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It is better if you could try to sideload you large app to your local machine so that you can check if the error is related with Xbox One.

Comment: Installing on my local machine isn't a problem. I removed a bunch of content from the project and it deploys to the Xbox Visual Studio now. The App Package is about 2GB, so it seems to be something to do with size... but this seems really illogical.

Comment: You could try to view if the following workaround can resolve your issue:

1.  In Windows Device Portal, go to the File Explorer workspace
2.  Click the Browse link at the top right
3.  Follow the instructions in the pop-up dialog to run cmdkey.exe and store credentials for the console on your PC
4.  Use Windows Explorer or robocopy.exe to copy the game payload to the console’s UNC path

Comment: Thanks! I tried this and it worked, but I also found that there's a setting 'Manage Developer Storage' and this was limited to 5GB... Didn't even know it was there but that was the problem. Will add an answer. P.S. sorry for the delay, was out of office.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that theres a default limit on Dev storage, set to 5GB. This was the issue, you can change this by pressing the options button and selecting 'Manage Dev Storage'. Bit daft that it fails with an irrelevant error when the space is exceeded but that's the way it is. Problem solved once I'd expanded to 30GB.